# Webkit animation move only right edge of a rectangular div to the left

Tags: css, sass, webkit

Consider a div with 100% width and 100vh height. I want to shrink it to 50% width and for that only it's right hand edge has to come from 100% to 50%.

How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE:**

My HTML (it is react):

```
<div className={classNames("div-one", { "half-width": this.state.showRegistration })}>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.div-one {

  background: url("../../../assets/images/manhattan-min.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  min-height: 100vh;

}

.div-one.half-width {
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: right-to-left-div1 0.2s forwards;
  animation: right-to-left-div1 0.2s forwards;

}

@keyframes right-to-left-div1{
  from{left:10%}
  to{left:0%}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, post relevant css and html

Comment: @Morpheus I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you can just animate the width to 50%

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 500px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation: right-to-left-div1 0.2s forwards;
  animation: right-to-left-div1 0.2s forwards;
}

@keyframes right-to-left-div1{
  to {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I wanted exactly this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in another div, position the inner div to the left, and then transform the width.